# TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMouse' of undefined React Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, ecmascript-2017

I want to do  when the user clicks on Input Element and the button element in the form will change to Send icon from the microphone icon. My idea was to get the value from onClick or mouseEnter handler and pass it through the if-else statement and set the correct icon

Here is my Code
`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import InsertEmoticonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InsertEmoticon';
import AttachFileIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AttachFile';
import MicIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mic';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';

import styled from 'styled-components'
import './MessageSender.css'

export class MessageSender extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        bool: 'false'
    }
    this.onMouse = this.onMouse.bind(this);
}


onMouse(){
    this.setState({bool: "true"})
}

renderInput(formProps){
    
    return <input 
        onChange={formProps.input.onChange}
        value={formProps.input.value}
        placeholder="Message" 
        onClick={this.onMouse()}
    />
}

onSubmit(formValues){
    console.log(formValues);
}
check(){
    // return <Send />
    if(this.state.bool === 'true'){
        return <Send />
    }else{
        return <Mic />
    }
}

render() {
    return (
            <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                <Emotion />
                <Field  name="Message" component={this.renderInput} placeholder="Message"  />
                <Attach />
                <button>
                    {this.check()}
                </button>
            </form>
        
    )
}
}

const Emotion = styled(InsertEmoticonIcon)`
    width: 40px!important;
    height: 40px!important;
    color: rgb(170,170,170);
`

const Attach = styled(AttachFileIcon)`
    width: 40px!important;
    height: 40px!important;
    color: rgb(170,170,170);
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
`
const Mic = styled(MicIcon)`

`
const Send = styled(SendIcon)`

`

export default  reduxForm({
    form: 'message'
})(MessageSender);
```

`

Therefore, here is my [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIBie.png)

Help me please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I think using an arrow function will solve an issue with using `this`. And you shouldn't be calling the function when you pass it to `onClick`

```
renderInput = (formProps) => {
    
    return <input 
        onChange={formProps.input.onChange}
        value={formProps.input.value}
        placeholder="Message" 
        onClick={this.onMouse}
    />
}
```